# Asp.net MVC4 @Html.EditorFor .Where() Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, mvc-editor-templates

In my view i am using editortemplate as below:

edit.cshtml

```
@model NetasCrm.Models.CRM_OPP_DETAILS 

<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Çözüm</th>
        <th>Üretici</th>
        <th>Tarih</th>
        <th>Tutar</th>
        <th>Sil</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CRM_SOLUTION_DISTRIBUTION, new { Solutions = ViewBag.Solutions, Vendors = ViewBag.Vendors })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It is working but i am trying to do something(adding where clause.) as below to create an editor template for some of the items in my model.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CRM_SOLUTION_DISTRIBUTION.Where(p=>p.AMOUNT != 0), new { Solutions = ViewBag.Solutions, Vendors = ViewBag.Vendors })
```

I am getting the below error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.XxxFor` expects a lambda expression that selects a property from the model. This is used  to identify the property of the model which will be edited.

What you're trying to achieve is probably what you can do with an editor template.

Interesting articles on editor templates and their implementation:

- [Quick Tips About ASP.NET MVC – Editor Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx)
- [Brad Wilson: ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

In the second article you can see that if you have a custom class with the data you want to edit, you can create a template which is automatically used for your editor if you give it the right name and save it in the right place. You can make a class with a single field and include it in your model instead of the original property. This also allows to edit several properties at once (declaring a class with those properties)

Othe option would be a custom html helper:

- [Creating Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) (NOTE: this technique will work perfectly with C#/Razor syntax)

Answer (score 3):

It's not how `@Html.EditorFor()` should be used, error message clear states about that.

To render what you want you may either use `Html.Partial()`, or create separate property in your model and move `Where` to it's getter.

Comment: I am trying to put input form for each item in model with using @html.editofor.. Html partial will be the long way to do this.. I am trying to play with model.